# Is using an array as a method possible?

Tags: ruby

I have this class:

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :player_fleet, :opponent_fleet
  @player_fleet = []
  @opponent_fleet = []
  ...
end
```

and create an instance like this:

```
my_game = Game.new
```

then use it like this:

```
my_game.opponent_fleet << opponent
```

which gives me this error:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why can't I treat an array like this? Do I have to create a method to push objects into the array?

Comment: in effect, you have to harness the initialize method to treat an array like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialize `@opponent_fleet` at class level, so it's an instance variable of the class, not of the generated objects. Remember that in Ruby, even classes are objects :)

```
irb(main):001:0> class Game
irb(main):002:1>   @foo = 3
irb(main):003:1> end
irb(main):004:0> Game.instance_eval { @foo }
=> 3
irb(main):005:0> Game.new.instance_eval { @foo }
=> nil
```

You want to initialize it in a constructor instead:

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :player_fleet, :opponent_fleet

  def initialize
    @player_fleet = []
    @opponent_fleet = []
  end
end
```

Comment: @theTinMan As much as I appreciate your edit, I want the smiley back!

Comment: Remember, Stack Overflow is supposed to be the Wikipedia of programming. When do you see smileys in formal documents and encyclopedias? Don't be surprised if someone else comes along and removes it.

Comment: OK this is a subtle difference I haven't dealt with before. Thanks!

Comment: @theTinMan: I'm not surprised at all.